# Why does this regex in perl work for one word but not another?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to perl so please excuse me if my question seems obvious.  I made a small perl script that just examines itself to extract a particular substring I'm looking for and I'm getting results that I can't explain.  Here is the script:

```
use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @files;
find( 
    sub { push @files, $File::Find::name unless -d; }, 
    "."
);

my @filteredfiles = grep(/.pl/, @files);

foreach my $fileName (@filteredfiles)
{
open (my $fh, $fileName) or die "Could not open file $fileName";

while (my $row = <$fh>)
{
    chomp $row;
    if ($row =~ /file/)
    {
        my ($substring) = $row =~ /file\(([^\)]*)\)/;
        print "$substring\n" if $substring;
    }
}

close $fh;
}

# file(stuff)
# directory(stuff)
```

Now, when I run this, I get the following output:

```
stuff
[^\
```

1. Why is it printing the lines out of order?  Since the "stuff" line occurs later in the file, shouldn't it print later?
2. Why is it printing that second line wrong?  It should be "`\(([^\`".  It's missing the first 3 characters.
3. If I change my regex to the following: `/directory\(([^\)]*)\)/`, I get no output.  The only difference is the word.  It should be finding the second comment.  What is going on here?

Comment: Did you also change the condition for the `if` block that surrounds it?

Comment: For me, this just prints `stuff`, not `[^\ `. The regex can't match itself because of the backslash between `file` and `(`! Do you have any other filenames *containing* `pl` in the same directory? Perhaps previous versions of the same script?

Comment: Ok, that was an obvious answer that I was banging head against for the last hour.  No, I forgot to change the if statement.  Thank you for that.  As for the second comment, no I don't have any other pl files in the directory.

Comment: Note that `/.pl/` matches any word containing any character followed by `pl`, for example the word `example`. The `.` is not a literal dot but matches any (non-newline) character. The regex is not anchored to match only at the end. You probably intended `/\.pl$/` to filter the file names. Since the character sequence `[^\ ` is fairly unique, maybe they are from a hidden backup file of a previous version of the script?

Comment: Ok, I think I realized what's going on.  It looks like the $File::Find::name does a recursive directory search, so it was finding a file several sub-directories below.  And yes, I need to change the regex as you suggested.  Thanks.

Comment: (1) Print the full path each time you find the phrase. MIght as well print the whole line `$row`, too (2) There is no need for an `if` first to see whether there's `file` word, then a match containing that word.  Test on the match you need, `if (my ($substr) =~ /file.../) { ... }`.

Comment: zdim, is there any way to get it to store the substring during the check, so that I don't have to run the regex a second time in order to print it?

Comment: The `if (...)` in my comment above stores the capture in `$substr` variable, which is then available within the scope delmited by `{ ... }` of that `if`.  So yes you have the 'catch' in `$substr`.  Is this what you mean?  See the full answer by @Sinan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `use 5.006` kind of odd if you are just beginning to learn Perl ... That is an ancient version.
2. You should not build a potentially huge list of all files in all locations under the current directory and then filter it. Instead, push only the files you want to the list.
3. Especially with escaped meta characters, regex patterns can be become hard to read very quickly, so use the `/x` modifier to insert some whitespace into those patterns.
4. You do not have to match twice: Just check & capture at the same time.
5. If `open` fails, include the reason in the error message.
6. Your second question above does not make sense. You seem to expect your pattern to match the literal string `file\(([^\)]*)\)/`, but it cannot.

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @files;

find(
    sub {
        return if -d;
        return unless / [.] pl \z/x;
        push @files, $File::Find::name;
    },
    '.',
);

for my $file ( @files ) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file
        or die "Could not open file $file: $!";

    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        if (my ($substring) = ($line =~ m{ (?:file|directory) \( ([^\)]*) \) }x)) {
            print "$substring\n";
        }
    }

    close $fh;
}

# file(stuff)
# directory(other)
```

Output:

```
stuff
other
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I will keep those in mind.  Strangely, with the Padre IDE, everything after the /x is no longer recognized as proper syntax.